# Recursive function to find a factorial of a fraction (python)

Tags: python, function, recursion, factorial

Okay so my problem is this:

Define a recursive function that takes a positive natural number n and returns the sum 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n.

My function so far looks like this:

```
def harmonic(n):
    """Natural Number -> number"""
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1/n * harmonic(n-1)
```

When I run it and input numbers for n, it only returns the floating point representing the fraction of 1/n instead of the factorial. There must be something wrong with my else statement, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: The function works for me (in Python 3): `harmonic(3)` produces `0.16666666666666666`, `harmonic(10)` produces `2.7557319223985883e-07`.

Comment: On Python 2, where `/` with integer operands is floor division, you get `0` for any natural `n`.

Comment: in python 2 `/` is integer division! you need to do `from __future__ import division`

Comment: the description says `+` but in your function you multiply... that can't be right.

Comment: It seems you've written incorrect code. First of all, the base case should be for n == 1, not n == 0. Second, you're using the multiplication operator instead of addition.

Comment: wow I am amazingly dumb thanks guys lol. With the addition it works perfectly I just totally missed that